# How do I write personalized endpoints in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I have personalized custom fields in Wordpress as well as additional things like "user_meta". I've even added some custom fields in the table to some post types.
Now I can call or write classic wordpress variables using wp-rest-api. But it cannot interfere with the private areas I add. There are different types of scenarios, prerequisites and different types that allow you to read / write to different fields, for example: `"POST: https: //example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts? Title = .... & content = ... "`function to add a new text.

Well my font was "fruits" though. Example: `"POST: https: //example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/fruits? Title = .... & content = ...."` How do I write a custom endpoint?

Comment: Please try this https://www.tychesoftwares.com/creating-custom-api-endpoints-in-the-wordpress-rest-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple and easy way to understand how to create a custom endpoint in WordPress rest api this website will be helpful: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Below example will help you more to understand about the basic of custom end points:

GET: https: //example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/hello/world

**Define Action:**

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function(){
    register_rest_route( 'wp/v2/hello', 'world', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'rest_hello_world'
    ));
});
```

**Call back function Definition:**

```
function rest_hello_world(){
   return "Hello World";
}
```

In order to create a **POST** method call simply change the method parameter as a POST:

```
register_rest_route( 'wp/v2/hello', 'world', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'rest_hello_world'
));
```

Hope it will help you to understand the basic fundamental for creating custom endpoints!

Cheers
Jenil